# Windows Batch - Move files to folder parent & Remove empty subfolders

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, context-menu

I found several such questions and tried to adapt the answers to my needs but no luck so far. I'm trying to create two context menu entries in Windows 7 that would:

1. Move all files from subfolders in a given folder to the parent folder. Duplicates should be renamed to `Filename-Duplicate` but not deleted.
2. Delete all empty subfolders.

I was able to successfully create the needed entries in:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete Empty Subfolders\command
```

and

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Move all subfiles here\command
```

The commands (and I think here lies the problem) are as follows for the two:

```
for /r ROOT %%d in (*.*) do move "%%d" "%1\"
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

When I select a folder that I created for testing this and select either one from the context menu it seems the batch file on disk where the Registry entry points to is found and executed but with no result.

I think the problem is the commands themselves. I'm not very experienced with **FOR** either. If this can be accomplished with PowerShell I'm open to that option. If at all possible I would avoid using external dependencies such as 3rd party apps to execute the commands.

Comment: The step 2 of your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34025977/694360

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your command. Instead it is related to the Registry because when you do it like this Windows will start looking for a program called `for.exe`

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\for.exe
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\for.exe
```

and then it starts looking for your program `for.*` in System32 and the Windows directories. When this fails it returns an error.

As a beginning try to make a .bat file and put your commands in it.
In the Registry try to refer to the full path of your batch file.

P.S: You will have another problem with long file names.

Comment: That's what im doing already but it's not working but it doesent throw any error either. Just silently fails. Image: http://i.imgur.com/IjKgmqW.jpg

Comment: remove all the double quotes from the image

Comment: try to catch the log with Process Monitor and search your command line file and continue tracing

Comment: Ok. Some progress. Removed double quotes from both registry values as you suggested and tweaked the commands themselves a bit. Now empty folders are removed and it appears to work correctly. The problem was `DIR /S` flag. As for moving files to parent folder it works but duplicates are overwritten and result is a single copy. And what about those long filenames?